# Why needs a cross-compiler when install OpenCV in Ubuntu 16.04 ARM

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, arm

I want to install OpenCV on arm board installed ubuntu 16.04 arm OS.

Most of the docs. install OpenCV using a cross-compiler.

I've never used cross-compiler, I have a few question about it

1. Why do I need use cross-compiler to install OpenCV?
2. If I install using a cross-compiler, then always host-computer need when any of source code using OpenCV running?

Comment: 1. ARM architecture (e.g. smartphone) is different from X86 architecture (e.g. regular laptop), that is why you need to build OpenCV to target ARM architecture. Other option should be to build directly OpenCV on the target machine but it will take much more time and memory for the build. 2. No.

Comment: if you have space you can build on your target machine with the target, non-cross, tools.   But if you dont have space for the tools, source, etc, which is not uncommon, then you build elsewhere that has space like your development machine.  if that is not the same target/tools then you need to use a cross compiler to BUILD.  then move the binary/data over to the target to RUN (on the target)